# GeoWebCache WMTS GetTile Request with HTTP POST KVP encoding

Tags: geowebcache, wmts, post, http

WMTS [specifies](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=35326) GetTile requests using HTTP POST, by simply encoding all request params in the body. Is this supported by GWC, and if so, what headers etc. do I have to set?

I naively tried this:

```
POST http://myserver.com/services/wmts

service=WMTS
request=GetTile
version=1.0.0
layer=mylayer
format=image%2Fpng
tilecol=12
tilerow=34
```

Which gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExceptionReport version="1.1.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://geowebcache.org/schema/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="request">
    <ExceptionText>Missing Request parameter</ExceptionText>
  </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the GetCapabilities response for GeoServer's WMTS service you will see it only advertises GET.

```
<ows:Operation name="GetTile">
  <ows:DCP>
    <ows:HTTP>
      <ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?">
        <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
          <ows:AllowedValues>
            <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
          </ows:AllowedValues>
        </ows:Constraint>
      </ows:Get>
    </ows:HTTP>
  </ows:DCP>
</ows:Operation>
```

Comment: Bummer. Would it be hard to add? If somebody could point me to the right places I'm willing to do it.

Comment: no idea, probably not - http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/docguide/contributing.html